# Covariant powerset functor and products

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I'm sorry for my silly doubt. Consider the covariant powerset functor $\mathcal{P}$. It is obvious that $\mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$.

Does the same inclusion hold for any iteration of $\mathcal{P}$, i.e. is it true that

$$
\mathcal{P}^n(X) \times \mathcal{P}^n(Y) \subseteq \mathcal{P}^n(X \times Y)
$$
for any $n \ge 2$?

More in general, allowing $n$ to be also $0$ (so that $\mathcal{P}^0(X)=X$), we get the obvious equality. Furthermore, if we take $(\mathcal{P}^0 \times \mathcal{P}^0)(X) \times (\mathcal{P}^0 \times \mathcal{P}^0)(Y)=(X \times X) \times (Y \times Y)$, we see that it is isomorphic to $(X \times Y) \times (X\times Y)$.

Now, it is in general true that $\prod\limits_{k_1,\dots,k_n \ge 0; \,\, n \, finite} (\mathcal{P}^{k_1} \times \mathcal{P}^{k_n})(X) \times (\mathcal{P}^{k_1} \times \mathcal{P}^{k_n})(Y)$ is isomorphic to a subset of $(\mathcal{P}^{k_1} \times \mathcal{P}^{k_n})(X \times Y)$?

Comment: Category-theoretically, there is a natural map the other way around: $F (X \times Y) \to F (X) \times F (Y)$, for any functor $F$ whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question, that $\mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(Y)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X\times Y)$, is not correct. The elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(Y)$ are ordered pairs of sets, while the elements of $ \mathcal{P}(X\times Y)$ are sets of ordered pairs.

I suppose what you really mean is that there is a natural map $\mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(Y)\to \mathcal{P}(X\times Y)$. Probably the one you're thinking of is the map $(A,B)\mapsto A\times B$. But this map is not injective (unless both $X$ and $Y$ are empty). E.g. $\varnothing\times \varnothing = \varnothing\times Y$.

So I'm not sure how to make sense of your question.